# Counting Number of records in each row in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Again I m sry fr that non-sense way of asking the question what i wanted to say that at the last column some rows have null values and some rows have a value which is not necessary.. So what i wanted to do to delete those rows which have not null values in last column and then deleting the whole last column...

The Table looks like this..:

```
     Col1    Col2    Col3     Col4
      A       A       A       A             

      B       B       B

      C       C       C

      D       D       D       D
```

So here i want to keep the row 2 and 3 and delete the row 1 and 4..Then deleting the whole column 4...

Comment: Do you expect that number of columns in the same table will be different from row to row? This not how SQL works

Comment: I don't understand what "count ... columns row by row" means. Can you show your table structure, a sample row you would delete, and a sample row you would keep?

Comment: **WHAT!?!?!?!!** The number of columns is a fixed number for any given table - it doesn't vary from row to row....... you're not making a lot of sense here.... you need to rephrase your question to explain in more detail what you're trying to achieve......

Comment: Number of columns for each row will be the same, what do you want to do?

Comment: Pardon? You define the model of your table, so the number of columns is ... "predictable".

Comment: i did not know that different rows can have different number of columns in same table.

Comment: I'm guessing it's just a terminology problem. Maybe he means counting columns that contain NULL or non-NULL values.

Comment: @Aaron: Maybe, but is that so very difficult to tell explicitely?

Comment: @Tim I know, I'm trying to push for better info from the OP. Just seems silly for 20 people to jump on the person for what is clearly a language barrier issue.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: At first I thought you were slightly exaggerating about 20 people, but then if we assumed you were using base-3 notation, 20 would be very precise. :)

Comment: Yeah, my count was fuzzy, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is based on your comment:

> Oopss!!! i am extremely sorry fr making a mess..:( what i wanted to
>   say that at the last column some rows have null values and some rows
>   have a value which is not necessary.. So what i wanted to do to delete
>   those rows which **have not null values in last column** and then deleting
>   the whole last column..

Here it is:

```
Delete from dbo.YourTable Where Last_Column IS NOT NULL
```

After that, dropping the column is easy if you go to table right click -> design
If it doesn't let you drop the column due to an error, you should do this:
Tools -> Options -> Designers-> Uncheck "Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation"

I'd suggest that you undo that change after you're done though.

Best of luck =)

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do won't work because they'll all have the same number of columns.

So don't waste your time trying to implement it because it won't solve whatever problem you're trying to solve!

Comment: Oopss!!! i am extremely sorry fr making a mess..:(
what i wanted to say that at the last column some rows have null values and some rows have a value which is not necessary..

So what i wanted to do to delete those rows which have not null values in last column and then deleting the whole last column...

Comment: Then please re-word your question and show a row you want to keep and a row you want to delete.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE dbo.table WHERE Col4 IS NOT NULL;
```